# Dataset from SQL Table View, but update the according tables

Tags: c#, sql, view, tableadapter

I'm populating a DataSet with a SQL Table View, the view provides data from 2 SQL commands connected via UNION.

```
Select ID,A,B,C,[...],'Appointment' from Appointments
Union
Select ID,A,B,C,[...],'Task' from Tasks
```

I'm displaying the data in a grid view and the end user can change the data.
Via ID and the fields 'Appointment' / 'Task', i'm able to identify the edited record.
But how can i Update the according record in the according tables?